# Creating complex tables in views in Drupal 7

Tags: views, theming

I was trying to make a report via views in Drupal 7. It's quite easy to generate a table with the headers being the labels of the fields, like the following (being very straightforward):

```
:---------:----------:----------:----------:
| Label A | Label B  | Label C  | Label D  |
:---------:----------:----------:----------:
| Value A | Value B  | Value C  | Value D  |
:---------:----------:----------:----------:
|Value A' |Value B'  |Value C'  |Value D'  |
:---------:----------:----------:----------:
```

However, I am getting stumped at creating the following complex table:

```
:---------:----------:----------:----------:
|     Header A       |      Header B       |
:---------:----------:----------:----------:
| Label A | Label B  | Label C  | Label D  |
:---------:----------:----------:----------:
| Value A | Value B  | Value C  | Value D  |
:---------:----------:----------:----------:
|Value A' |Value B'  |Value C'  |Value D'  |
:---------:----------:----------:----------:
```

Any ideas on how to approach this? Thanks :)

Comment: you can add a header and then style it in css to look like as if it part of the table

Answer (score 2):

The Views UI supports this.

Once you have your View configured, click on the "Settings" link in the Format section. You will then see a table that allow you to choose which column each field should appear in. See screenshot below. In this example, if you wanted the `Author uid` and `Nid` fields to appear in the same column, you would just select `Author uid` from the select list next to `Nid` (or vice versa).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [theme_table](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) and colspan attribute

```
$header = array( array('data' => 'Header A', 'colspan' => 2), array('data' => 'Header B', 'colspan' => 2));
$rows[] = array('Label A', 'Label B', 'Label C', 'Label D');
$rows[] = array('value A', 'value B', 'value C', 'value D');
$rows[] = array('value A', 'value B', 'value C', 'value D');
$rows[] = array('value A', 'value B', 'value C', 'value D');
$output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' =>  $attributes));

print $output;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really describe how to make the output of a view follow this format.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I could not find a working answer anywhere and, since this was the best description of the question, I think a working solution here would benefit others.

The Views UI does not yet support two header rows. Thus you need to override the template for styling the views table output.

1. Copy the views/theme/views-view-table.tpl.php template file to your own theme or module directory.
2. Rename it to make it specific to your particular view. To determine what this name should be, click on the "Theme: Information" under the "Other" category in your edit view UI and then find the template name that includes your views machine name and is in the "Style Output" bullet.

[image: Screenshot of the Views Edit UI][image: Screenshot of the Theme Information Overlay]

3. Ensure your template is detected. To check that it has been detected click the "Rescan Template Files" button at the bottom of the Theme Information opened above. If you template has been detected it will be bolded within the "Style Output" bullet.

   a) Custom Theme: If you copied the template file into a theme directory in step 1 then the new template should be automatically detected.

   b) Custom Module: Your template will not be automatically detected, therefore you need to use hook_theme to register your new template. For example,

   ```
   function mymodulename_theme() {
     $items = array();

     // Notice that the key for this array is the name of your template
     // with all dashes replaced by underscores.
     $items['views_view_table__cb_planned_crosses'] = array(
       'arguments' => array(
               'view' => NULL, 
               'title' => NULL, 
               'header' => NULL, 
               'fields' => NULL, 
               'class' => NULL, 
               'row_classes' => NULL, 
               'rows' => NULL
           ),
           // Replace views-view-table--cb-planned-crosses with the
           // name of your template.
           'template' => 'views-view-table--cb-planned-crosses',
           'base hook' => 'views_view_table',
           // Replace cross_manage with the name of your module.
           'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'cross_manage') . '/theme/templates',
     );

     return $items;
   }
   ```
4. Finally, edit the template file and use HTML/PHP to add an additional header row within `thead`. For simplicity, I am going to show a hardcoded example but I recommend processing the fields in the view and using appropriate criteria to determine programatically which fields should be under which columns.

   ```
       <thead>
         <!-- Add your custom grouping header -->
         <tr>
           <th colspan="2">Header A</th>
           <th colspan="2">Header B</th>
         </tr>
         <!-- Pre-existing Header code -->
         <tr>
           <?php foreach ($header as $field => $label): ?>
             <th <?php if ($header_classes[$field]) { print 'class="'. $header_classes[$field] . '" '; } ?>>
               <?php print $label; ?>
             </th>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
         </tr>
       </thead>
   ```